# API Router Depends Not Compatible with Depend()

Tags: python, import, socket.io, fastapi

#### Description

I am writing a FastAPI app for making multiplayer chess games. But unfortunately I am stuck on a circular import problem (or so I am guessing) and I'm not able to move forward. Basically I have a socket manager variable in the `api/main.py` which needs to be imported in `api/endpoints/game.py`, but in `api/main.py` I also include the API routers. So whenever I include the API routers it would call that module, which would then call `api/main.py` which would again call `game.py` to include the router, therefore creating a circular imports problem. This is the complete python traceback: [here](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/pitalutuva.py).

#### Code

The code can be seen on GitHub, here it the repository link https://github.com/p0lygun/astounding-arapaimas/tree/feature/api/games/api.

#### My Tries

I tried all the "hacks" of injecting the module using `sys` and `os` but nope they too caused the same problem. I tried moving the `socket_manager` into a completely different file too but that would too cause the same problem.

If any other information is required let me know, posting a question for the first time so not so sure what all is needed. Thanks!

### Edits

##### Edit 1

`codemation#0324` on discord suggested a better way to access the socket manager like this:

[image]

Interestingly I get the [same error](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ezujutowav.py) afterwards too.

##### Edit 2

The problem is happening along the lines where I add JWT Auth depend into the API Router and then use `Depend(get_db)` in the endpoint definition function. An alternative would be not `Depend` the `get_db()` and just call it normally and pass it on to the CRUD functions for the timing.

To be clear, when I remove `, dependencies=[Depends(auth.JWTBearer())]` it works perfectly.

Comment: I think the problem is not all with the imports, but rather with the `Depends(get_db())` due to [this](https://github.com/p0lygun/astounding-arapaimas/blob/fe5e0e91ca9c7517ceb509febefa5ff1621d81fa/api/endpoints/games.py#L13) line. There was also a import definition error which is fixed [here](https://github.com/p0lygun/astounding-arapaimas/pull/13/commits/fe8e0029ec564abd9302511d17954ab6861378e4) but I still get the same error.